# phpstorm mercurial pre commit hook not executed

Tags: mercurial, phpstorm, mercurial-hook

I have this pre-commit hook set up in .hg/hgrc

```
[hooks]
pre-commit = python:commit.py:run
```

commit.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import os
 import time

 def run(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    datestring = time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
    filecontent = 'span.project-date-content:after {content:"'+datestring+'"}'
    with open('css/projectdate.css', 'w') as f:
        f.write(filecontent)

    return False
```

This works exactly as expected when I do a commit from the command line, however when I do a commit from within phpstorm the projectdate.css file does not get updated.

How can I get phpstorm to execute my (or any) pre-commit hook before commiting?